# How to fetch reviewer info from facebook page reviews to website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

I want to fetch reviews from the Facebook page to the website, I have the following settings in graph explorer:
{reviewer,recommendation_type,review_text,open_graph_story,rating,created_time,has_rating,has_review}
I can't get data of "reviewer" (I want the review author's name and photo), Can you tell me what could be the problem? Thanks in advance

[image]